# How to display the result of "toPrecision" without the scientific notation?

Tags: javascript

Based on http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/nfbasic2.html, following code will result in **5.6e+2**.

```
num = 555.55;
result = num.toPrecision(2); // result will equal 5.6e+2
```

How can I let the output of the result variable be displayed **without scientific notation** (i.e., e)?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To get a float with reduced precision, you could use `toPrecision()` like you do, and then parse the scientific notation with [parseFloat()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseFloat.asp), like so:

```
result = parseFloat(num.toPrecision(2));
```

If you do not wish to reduce precision, you could use [toFixed()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp) to get the number with a certain number of decimals.

Comment: That yields 2 decimals. Precision doesn't start counting from the decimal point, but from the first digit. `toPrecision(2)` for `"555.55"` would mean something like `toFixed(-1)` (which doesn't exist as it doesn't really make sense).

Comment: This is awesome. This nicely formats big numbers (`24823492.293849 --> 25000000`) as well as numbers with decimal dust (e.g. 1/5 + 1/20 - 1/200 + 1/400 + 1/10 = 0.34750000000000003 --> 0.35`)

Comment: A nice feature of `toPrecision()` is that it retains trailing zeros, indicating the precision of the result (eg `(0.5).toPrecision(2)` gives "0.50"). If you want to keep this behaviour, you could use `result = num.toPrecision(2).includes('e') ? parseFloat(num.toPrecision(2)) : num.toPrecision(2)`.

Comment: If you want to also remove very small numbers like 3.1e-31 : `parseFloat((Math.round(value * 100000) /100000).toPrecision(2))`

Answer (score 21):

```
Number((555.55).toPrecision(2))
```

http://jsfiddle.net/K5GRb/

Comment: +1, and deleted my own answer. This is completely the way to go.

Comment: This is preferable over parseFloat((555.55).toPrecision(2))

Comment: @asmmahmud: Why it is preferable over parseFloat?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar desire to preserve a certain amount of precision, not have trailing zeros, and not have scientific notation.  I think the following function works:

```
function toDecimalPrecision(val, digits) {
  val = (+val).toPrecision(digits);
  if (val.indexOf('e') >= 0) {
    val = (+val).toString();
  } else if (val.indexOf('.') >= 0) {
    val = val.replace(/(\.|)0+$/, '');
  }
  return val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
result = Math.ceil(555.55);
```

Comment: This yields `556`, not `560` which `5.6e+2` represents.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me [Typescript]:

```
const toDecimalPrecision = (value: number, digits: number) => {
  let fixed = 2
  const result = parseFloat(value.toPrecision(digits))
  while (parseFloat(result.toFixed(fixed)) !== result && fixed < 20) {
    fixed++
  }
  return result.toFixed(fixed)
}
```

Answer (score -3):

`eval` is evil.

Do

`var result = num.toPrecision(2).toString(10);`

instead.

Comment: toPrecision returns a string, so calling toString on that wouldn't make a difference.