# Receiving wrong % calculation

Tags: javascript

I'm running the following function:

```js
function convertToPercent(num, max, min) {
  min = min ? min : 0;
  var result = (num - min) / (max - min) * 100;
  return result.toPrecision(2);
}

// Sample data
var nationData = {
  customConfirmed: 53498798,
  population: 39987543
};

var rateConfirmed = convertToPercent(nationData.customConfirmed, nationData.population);

console.log(rateConfirmed);
```

But as a result I get

```
1.3e+2%
```

Why is there an `e`?

Comment: The notation `e` is for power of 10, `1.3e+2` means `1.3*100`, `2e4` is `2*10000`...

Comment: See [*How to display the result of “toPrecision” without the scientific notation?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689142/how-to-display-the-result-of-toprecision-without-the-scientific-notation) (use `parseFloat(result.toPrecision(2))`).

Comment: `.toPrecision([precision])` returns _"A string representing a `Number` object in fixed-point or exponential notation rounded to `precision` **significant digits**."_ - You're telling `.toPrecision()` that the string representation should consist of two numbers. The only possible way for 130 is its scientific notation `1.3 e+2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`toPrecision(2)` returns a string representation of a number with 2 significant digits, which is likely not what you want. If you have a number like `132`, `toPrecision` will return `1.3e2`, which means `1.3*100`, or 130. Use `toFixed(2)` if you want a string representation that has 2 decimal places.

Comment: This answer could be improved if you also explain what the e means

Comment: Also, not the toPrecision returns a string, not a number

Comment: But *toFixed* will return 132.00 unless you do something like `(num / 100).toFixed(2) * 100`, or just `Math.round(num)`.

Answer (score 0):

toFixed(n) provides n length after the decimal point; toPrecision(x) provides x total length.

Example 
`(1*100).toFixed(2);//"100.00"
(1*100).toPrecision(2);//"1.0e+2"`

use this

```
   function convertToPercent(num, max, min) {
    min = min ? min : 0;
    var result = (num - min) / (max - min) * 100;
    return result.toFixed(2);
}
```